# Как правильно составить запрос? MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, запрос

БД MS SQL. Написал запрос, который должен мне возвращать список пользователей. Но столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Если у пользователя несколько номеров телефона (таблица ClientsPhones), то в возвращаемом списке пользователь будет продублирован столько же раз, сколько у него номеров телефона. Никак не могу понять как сделать так, что бы клиент не дублировался в списке.

```
DECLARE
       @Phone        NVARCHAR(64) = NULL,
       @Email        NVARCHAR(256) = NULL
SELECT t1.UserId,
       t2.CityId,
       t3.Balance,
       t1.FIO
FROM UsersInfo AS t1
       JOIN UsersToCity AS t2 ON t2.UserId = t1.UserId
       JOIN AccountsBalance AS t3 ON t1.UserId = t3.UserId
       JOIN ClientsPhones AS t4 ON t1.UserId = t4.UserId
WHERE (@Phone IS NULL OR t4.NormalizedPhone LIKE @Phone + '%')
  AND (@Email IS NULL OR t1.Email LIKE @Email + '%' COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AI)
```

Подскажите как это можно исправить.

Comment: а какой из номеров вам нужен?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov нужен сам факт того что там есть номер

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так, например:

```
 DECLARE
           @Phone        NVARCHAR(64) = NULL,
           @Email        NVARCHAR(256) = NULL
    SELECT t1.UserId,
           t2.CityId,
           t3.Balance,
           t1.FIO
    FROM UsersInfo AS t1
           JOIN UsersToCity AS t2 ON t2.UserId = t1.UserId
           JOIN AccountsBalance AS t3 ON t1.UserId = t3.UserId
           CROSS APPLY ( 
                SELECT TOP 1 NormalizedPhone 
                FROM ClientsPhones 
                WHERE UserId = t1.UserId
                    AND (@Phone IS NULL OR NormalizedPhone LIKE @Phone + '%')
                ) cf
    WHERE (@Email IS NULL OR t1.Email LIKE @Email + '%' COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AI)
```

Или вообще просто добавить `DISTINCT`:

```
DECLARE
       @Phone        NVARCHAR(64) = NULL,
       @Email        NVARCHAR(256) = NULL
SELECT DISTINCT t1.UserId,
       t2.CityId,
       t3.Balance,
       t1.FIO
FROM UsersInfo AS t1
       JOIN UsersToCity AS t2 ON t2.UserId = t1.UserId
       JOIN AccountsBalance AS t3 ON t1.UserId = t3.UserId
       JOIN ClientsPhones AS t4 ON t1.UserId = t4.UserId
WHERE (@Phone IS NULL OR t4.NormalizedPhone LIKE @Phone + '%')
  AND (@Email IS NULL OR t1.Email LIKE @Email + '%' COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AI)
```

Все зависит от того, какой в итоге нужен результат.

Comment: Спасибо, вариант с Distinct то что мне необходимо